# Python: list/array, remove doubled words string

Tags: python

I want to filter only elements that have only one word and make a new array of it.
How could I do this in Python?

Array:

```
['somewhat', 'all', 'dictator', 'was called', 'was', 'main director', 'in']
```

NewArray should be:

```
['somewhat', 'all', 'dictator', 'was', 'in']
```

Comment: Use filter along with string.split function for it

Comment: @Clover, it's sufficient to check for space, no need to split

Comment: @buran yes that would be the better choice

Comment: @buran Not if they have single words with spaces in the strings

Comment: @MatthewBarlowe if they have space in the string, using split or just checking presence of space will yield same result (desired or not).

Comment: just check presence of space in string and filter accordingly

Comment: @buran no it won't if you check for space in a string like this `' was'` it will exclude based on the presence of the space while `split` will not

Comment: @MatthewBarlowe, ok that's border case, but it's up to OP how it should be treated - i.e. is `' was'` a single word at all as per their use case.

Comment: @Buran its a single word just based on language and has nothing to do with their use case. Unless you are sanitizing the text in other ways just checking for spaces is a poor assumption

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
a= ['somewhat', 'all', 'dictator', 'was called', 'was', 'main director', 'in']

print([i for i in a if " " not in i])
```

Output:

```
['somewhat', 'all', 'dictator', 'was', 'in']
```

Comment: @rozjni, glad to know, that it hepled you :)

Answer (score 2):

filter the list with a list comprehension

```
old_list = ['somewhat', 'all', 'dictator', 'was called', 'was', 'main director', 'in']


new_list = [x for x in old_list if len(x.split()) == 1]
```

Returns:

```
['somewhat', 'all', 'dictator', 'was', 'in']
```

Comment: your `old_list` is missing `[`

Answer (score 0):

Using re.match and filter

```
import re


MATCH_SINGLE_WORD = re.compile(r"^\w+$")

inp = ['somewhat', 'all', 'dictator', 'was called', 'was', 'main director', 'in']
out = filter(MATCH_SINGLE_WORD.match, inp)

print(list(out)) # If you need to print. Otherwise, out is a generator that can be traversed(once) later
```

This solution would handle \n or \t being present in word boundaries as well along with single whitespace character.

If you want to handle leading and trailing whitespaces,

```
import re
from operator import methodcaller

MATCH_SINGLE_WORD = re.compile(r"^\w+$")

inp = ['somewhat', 'all', 'dictator', 'was called', 'was', 'main director', 'in']
out = filter(MATCH_SINGLE_WORD.match, map(methodcaller("strip"), inp))
```